# Why am I not allowed to ask a question?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

I do not understand why should I be barred from asking questions despite having asked some question with very good reputations.

Comment: You have a lot of deleted questions, which counts against you in the eyes of the automatic question ban, cf. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10165/50583

Comment: I known this question isn't a title duplicate of the one I selected, but the answer there covers the bases very well. two piece of advice: stop asking us to calculate things (it's not what we do here and it will only get you more negative reaction which will *not* help with the automated limits and bans), and don't delete question for no reason.

Comment: Is there a way of permanently deleting my account?